# What is the difference between "Da ist..." and "Es ist...da"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

As a native English speaker, it is most natural for me to say "Da ist", because it closely mirrors "There is". However, I've seen "Es ist...da" to mean what appears to be the same thing. [Example:](https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/meaning-da/)

> **Es ist** noch ein bisschen Gemüsebrühe **da**.

Are they the same? When should I use one or the other?

Comment: [Es ist noch Suppe da](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaZ7hgZuRBE)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My two cents:

1. You want to stress that there is still that broth.

> **Es** ist noch ein bisschen Gemüsebrühe **da**.

2. You want to stress *where* there is still broth.

> **Da** ist noch ein bisschen Gemüsebrühe.

Answer (score 7):

"Es ist (noch) ... da" means "there is ... left". You use this to state that this may change. In your example, with food, it means there is some left but someone may eat it. It can even be used as an indirect way of saying "help yourself".

"Da ist ein Vogel" means "There is a bird". You use this when you want to direct someone's attention, possibly with pointing (in this example).